# change name of rmarkdown pdf and title from a parameter in render call

Tags: r, r-markdown

Here is some R markdown code in a "test_param.Rmd" file:

````
---
output: pdf_document
params:
  number: "1"
title: `r params$number`
---

```{r setup, include=TRUE}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

```

```{r one, include = TRUE}

i = 2
#data = data.frame(x = c(1,2,3))

#for(i in 1:dim(data)[1]){

 # plot(i*1000)

#}

```

`r params$number`
````

that is called using a .r file here:

```
library(rmarkdown)

rmarkdown::render("C://Users//me//Desktop//test_param.Rmd", 
                  params = list(number= "1"))
```

I get this error when I run the .r

```
Error in yaml::yaml.load(enc2utf8(string), ...) : 
  Scanner error: while scanning for the next token at line 4, column 8found character that cannot start any token at line 4, column 8
```

Any idea why?

I am using ``  not '' to do the  title: `r params$number`

Answer (score 4):

Question 1 is nicely answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31862074/1274516), you can use `params` to inject a new title into the YAML config:

```
---
output: html_document
params: 
    new_title: "My Title!"
title: "`r params$new_title`"
---
```

Then the output filenames for rendered files can be set by the `output_file` parameter of `rmarkdown::render`.

Comment: are those are backtick correct?  when I do `r params$new_title` I get the error Error in yaml::yaml.load(enc2utf8(string), ...) : 
  Scanner error: while scanning for the next token at line 4, column 8found character that cannot start any token at line 4, column 8 . Can you see updated code?

Comment: You're right, this now needs to be: `"\`r params$new_title\`"` (quotes around backticks). I'll update the answer

Comment: I tried "`r paste0(params$MyParam, " test paste")`" and it does not work. Is there a way to paste text on to the title?

Comment: How about building the title on the R side rather than the Rmd side for simplicity? (Also it might be worth reverting your question edits so this all makes sense for people googling this same problem later.)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who comes across this, instead of trying to call `paste` you can use something like``` "``r params$MyParam` test paste`" ```. such as:

``` ---
output: html_document
params: 
    new_title: "My Title!"
title: "``r params$new_title` test paste`"
--- ```

This worked using RStudio 1.0.143 with R 3.4.0