# Rmarkdown tab name in browser

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm struggling with what to Google to start solving this one. It might be a Windows question and not an R question but I could do with some help.

I am using `rmarkdown::render` to generate html reports. I have a `master.Rmd` which calls some `child_docs`. I use the argument `output_file =` to name the html document. This works fine and I can successfully generate documents called `my_report1.html`. When I open the html document in my browser (both Chrome and FireFox) the browser tab is labelled as `master.utf8.md`:

[image: Chrome tab label]

In the past the tab label used to be `my_report1.html`. I want to fix this because I regularly have multiple reports open and navigating between the tabs to find which report I want is now painful.

Any thoughts on what to check?

The YAML:

```
---
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
params:
  lot: 1
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
---
```

Chunk setup:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
## GLobal chunk options
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)
```
````

Update: I think this is to do with the YAML `title:`. I'm going to open a new question with a better example.

Comment: Well with Google Chrome, the tab name on my pc is the same as the file name. So my ``test.html`` name in the tab is ``test``. I'm not sure why yours is behaving differently.

Comment: Can you try : ``---

output:

  html_document:

    keep_md: FALSE

---`` ?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I get the same results with `keep_md: FALSE`

Comment: I get this output after the knit `output file: master.knit.md`, followed by ..blah...`/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS master.utf8.md`

Comment: Can you share the code you are using in the header and R options chunk from your Markdown file please?

Comment: I've added the info above. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to cobble together a work around for this. The tab name in a browser comes from the `title` declared in the YAML even if you supply a file name to `output_file` in `rmarkdown::render`. I wanted to set my title dynamically and this can be done with using the methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861569/setting-document-title-in-rmarkdown-from-parameters), example:

````
---
output: html_document
--- 

```{r}
title_var <- "Sample Title"
```    
---
title: `r title_var`
---
````

However, I needed an extra work around to suppress the title because I didn't actually want it to make a title. This can be done by using the following css (top of doc or separate file):

```
<style>
  .title{
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```