# R Markdown: modify document title with javascript

Tags: javascript, r, r-markdown

With R Markdown, I would like to set the title of the document and it depends on R code that will be run inside this Rmd file.

So I try to use javascript to set the title.

I tried this following code, but it doesn't work:

```
document.title = "`r title_value`";
```

I think that I should to find the correct way to set the title. For example, to change the text in the navbar, I succeded with the following code:

```
document.querySelector(".navbar-header > span.navbar-brand").innerHTML = "`r title_value`";
```

Comment: Probably no need for JS. See https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/dynamic-yaml.html

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861569/setting-document-title-in-rmarkdown-from-parameters

Comment: Thank you stefan, I thought that yaml should always put in the beginning. now it is a good thing to know that you can put it anywhere

Comment: Haha. So did I. :D